# Validate a password in angular with reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, frontend, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using ng Reactive Forms for Password validation, I have a simple html input for password and warning paragraphs for password requirements

```
<div class=" field ">
    <label class="label">Password</label>
    <div class="control">
        <input class="input" type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Type password... ">

        <!-- Required validator -->
        <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="userCreateForm.controls['password'].touched && userCreateForm.controls['password'].errors?.['required']">Password is required!</p>

        <!-- Min length -->
        <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="userCreateForm.controls['password'].touched && userCreateForm.controls['password'].errors?.['minlength']">Password must be over 8 charachters!</p>

        <!-- Uppercase letter -->
        <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="userCreateForm.controls['password'].touched && !userCreateForm.controls['password'].errors?.['containsUpperLetter']">Password must contain at least one uppercase letter!</p>

        <!-- Numeric charachter -->
        <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="userCreateForm.controls['password'].touched && !userCreateForm.controls['password'].errors?.['containsNumber']">Password must contain at least one number!</p>

        <!-- Special charachter -->
        <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="userCreateForm.controls['password'].touched && !userCreateForm.controls['password'].errors?.['containsSpecialCharachter']">Password must contain at least one special charachter!</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I initialize form and add validators to password my function returns an object that contains properties of password

```
private initializeForm(): void {
        this.userCreateForm = new FormGroup({
            firstName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            lastName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            username: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), this.validateUsername.bind(this)]),
            password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), this.validatePassword.bind(this)]),
          });
}

private validatePassword(control: FormControl): ValidatorFn{
    const password = control.value;
      
    const errors: any = {
          containsUpperLetter: this.containsUpperLetter(password),
          containsNumber: this.containsNumber(password),
          containsSpecialCharachter: this.containsSpecialCharachter(password)
    }
   
    return errors;
}
```

Functions containsUpperLetter(), containsNumber(), containsSpecialCharachter(), are functions that return true or false. So the problem is that I'll always get an object error in return of function and ValidatorFn will threat it as error in password even if all properties are true, and I can not return null because I need properties from error object so my html would render properly. How to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FromBuilder and form.controls for this case.

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <mat-form-field class="mat-text-field" >
                                <input matInput placeholder="Confirm password" required formControlName="confirmPassword">
                                <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['confirmPassword'].hasError('requireConfirmPassword')">
                                    Confirm password is required!
                                </mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
      confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
    }, {
          validators: [this.requireConfirmPassword]
        });

requireConfirmPassword(form: FormGroup) {
    if (form.get('password').value !== form.get('confirmPassword').value) {
      return {requireConfirmPassword: true};
    }
    return null;
  }
```